# Dropdown selection based on the data from another dropdown in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a phone number drop down with list of countries with country code(India +91).Based on this selection, the country drop down should also populate values. If I select (India +91) in phone number drop down then the value in country drop down should change to (India). I am storing the country code and country in a json array. How can I do this using angular 5.

Comment: We can't help you edit your code if we don't know what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that you have 
html:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="code" (change)="onCodeChange($event)" >
<option *ngFor="let c of codeArr" [value]="c.id">{{c.value}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="country">
    <option *ngFor="let c of countryArr" [value]="c.id">{{c.value}}</option>
</select>
```

ts:

```
onCodeChange($event){
  this.country = $event.target.value;
}
```

I hope you get the idea, when you change the value(id) of the code dropdown you should assign the value(id) to country dropdown.

Comment: Thanks issue is resolved..I have one more requirement to change the validation of phone number based on the country code.Any idea on that. Have seen some docs but not much clear on it

Comment: Can you make the question more clear please? I did not get the concept well.

Comment: For example when user selects “United States +1” from Phone dropdown, the place holder of textfield will change to “201-555-0123” and validation is also done based on it.

Comment: so for the user may have to enter a mobile number in that format(eg:201-555-0123)otherwise it will show the message as invalid phone number

Comment: Okay, I got it. To accomplish that you can again use above-mentioned technique, when user selects country you get the input, and find the corresponding validation case in you categorized list. Then trigger the corresponding validation state. For example, lets say you have 4 different cases and countries are categorized in them, user chooses Germany, you look for the validation type of Germany in your lists and call the necessary validation type. I made it clear.

Comment: Of course, you will keep ready your validation cases(or functions) to be triggered when input is chosen.